# Compiling an existing project under Linux using Angular?

Tags: angular, linux, npm

We need to compile an existing Angular project, that was developed and compiles successfully under Windows 10, in Linux.

At first I installed WSL Ubuntu in Windows 10. I did `npm install` all went well. Then I tried to build my project using `ng build --prod --base-href /IC/` (which works on Windows) and got hung on

```
92% chunk asset optimization TerserPlugin
```

I read online and leared that this is a common problem running on WSL. So I have setup an Ubuntu VM under hyper-v, installed node and npm and tried again.

This time, while running `npm install` I get some errors, but if I run `sudo npm install` I pass those errors and see the `node-sass@4.11.0` compiles some c files, and then fails with the following:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ophir/.npm/_logs/2019-11-17T09_53_45_418Z-debug.log
```

Any ideas how to compile an angular project on Linux?

Comment: Your application compiles on Windows 10 with a given Node.js and npm version. Do you use the same Node.js and npm versions on Ubuntu as well?

Comment: Yes. I've checked that the versions match.

Comment: This topic on GitHub may help: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2662
I suspect that your installed Node.js version does not match the node-sass version that you have in your dependencies.